# Why won't my computer turn off?

Tags: windows-8, power-supply

I have recently replaced my old Corsair TX650M PSU with a new CoolerMaster Silent Pro Gold 800w PSU. With the old PSU when I turned off my computer from windows it would shut down and everything would turn off. The lights would turn off and the fans would stop turning. With my new power supply when I shut down windows It shows the usual shutting down dialog then my two monitors say "no signal" and turn off. The weird part however is that the lights stay on and the fans continue spinning forever until I manually hold the power button in for 4 seconds then finally everything shuts off. How can I emulate the previous behavior?

Comment: It sounds like the motherboard isn't sending the signal to the PSU to shut off...or the PSU isn't receiving it.

Comment: So you changed *only* the PSU, not the motherboard? If so, then it sounds like what happened was that your motherboard reset to default settings when you disconnected it (check the battery; it’s probably dead) or you cleared the CMOS. Enter your BIOS/EFI’s editor and set the power-mode to `S3` instead of `S1` or `Auto`.

Comment: @Synetech Correct I changed only the PSU, nothing else. I will try to find this option in the ASUS bios.

Comment: @Synetech I was unable to find that option.

Comment: @kinglime, well don’t look at me; I’m not psychic, so I have no idea what motherboard you have. `:-P`

Comment: @Synetech I was able to fix the issue thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. Here's what I did in this order:

1. I downloaded the newest BIOS for my motherboard and updated it.
2. I reset my motherboard to the default settings.
3. I turned off the computer and unplugged it. I then manually reset the CMOS (for those who don't know basically you move a connector from pins 1-2 to 2-3 for a couple seconds, then put it back. I believe it varies by motherboard.)
4. Lastly I reset the settings to default again (just to be safe) and then reset and booted into Windows.

When I sent the shut down command from Windows, the PC completely shut off as usual. I was able to detect that this was a hardware issue rather than software (at least on the OS level) by creating a USB boot-able version of Ubuntu. When I tried to shut down Ubuntu and had similar errors I knew nothing was wrong with the OS. I was able to narrow down my search queries and put together these steps. From what I can tell it appears this is an issue with ASUS motherboards. I hope this helps anyone who stumbles across it!