# My computer won't halt when I power it off from the OS

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

Years ago I have assembled a PC (Asus H100M-K, 850W Thermaltake Toughpower PSU no RGB, Coolermaster case). Since I use it as a server and upgrades are done offline, therefore I always pressed the poweroff button on the case to shut it off. I have never noticed that if I power it off or reboot it via the OS, the computer shuts down correctly, but then after roughly 5 seconds, it powers on again and the keeps powering down and up every 5 seconds.
In order to fix the issue I have to power off the PSU, and wait for 15 seconds. Then I can boot the machine. During the 15 seconds, I hear the PSU trying to powering on the machine at least once. This is weird and I think it could be due to the PSU holding some power after being cut off.

It's the only computer I have assembled that exhibits this issue. What could be?

I did:

- upgraded the BIOS
- reset the CMOS
- changed the battery
- inspected the board for defects
- detached and reattached all the cables and headers
- tested the RAM(s)
- booted with different OSes (live and installed)
- replaced CPU, RAM and disks

I saw [Why won't my computer turn off?](https://superuser.com/questions/506741/why-wont-my-computer-turn-off) and didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I would do a power reset. This is basically unplugging the power cable from the computer, then press and hold the powerbutton for 30 seconds to ensure all residual power is drained and static charges dissopate. Then plug in the power cable and turn it on and see if the problem still exists. Your PSU might need a replacement otherwise.

Comment: If I use the hardware buttons, the computer powers off as expected. It's the "software" part that does not work. At first, I thought that some headers were inverted, but SW Reset and Power have no polarity. I thought something related to S states, but I have no clue about which combination of settings is giving me this problem. As I recall, the issue was there as soon the PC was built, but I thought it was a problem with an external card which I removed immediately.

Comment: Yes, but I've seen too many times that some weird power residu is causing issues in software. So to rule this out, a full power-resset is necessary.

Comment: Your procedure works (as you said, it's the same as unplugging the power chord). Unfortunately i have no powerful PSU to replace to check that it is the PSU. Could it be something caused by me? some working connection, or simply mobo and PSU incompatible?

Comment: Holding the powerbutton for 30 seconds with the cable unplugged should be a more permanent fix. As in, shutting down from the OS should work normally too now. In that case, it is solved for now, and the problem can remain gone for years. If it still doesn't work from the OS, then the PSU needs to be replaced.